# How do I determine the length of a list in python?How do I determine the length of a list in python?How do I determine the length of a list in python?

Tags: python

If I have 6 or 7 element in a python list, how do I count the number of elements in the list?

Comment: You get the total number of elements with  `len(somelist)`. Have you tried the python tutorial?

Comment: What do you want the code to do if there aren't 6 or 7 items in the list?

Comment: `sum(1 for item in my_list)` is *a way* you could do this

Comment: _Why_ do you need the count? It may not be necessary to know because, for example, you can process all the elements in the list with `for elem in the_list:`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len), e.g.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> print len(l)
7
```

Given the basic nature of your question, I recommend that you read the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `len` function :

```
len([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

If you want to learn more about the len function :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_len.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows using lists', [count](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
In [5]: a=[1,3,4,6,6,7,6]

In [6]: a.count(6)
Out[6]: 3
In [7]: a.count(7)
Out[7]: 1
```

Or if you mean actual length of an array, rather than the number of occurrences of an element in a list, just use len:

```
In [8]: len(a)
Out[8]: 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

print len(a) # will equal 6
```